# Git pull fails : unable to update local ref

Tags: git, push, pull, git-extensions

I'm totally messed with my git repository. I can't push / pull remote branch..it disappeared from git extensions...

I use  Git Extensions 2.33 , msysgit  Git-1.7.11-preview20120710.exe

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe pull --progress "biometric" +refs/heads/try_merge:refs/remotes/biometric/try_merge
error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/biometric/try_merge: No such file or directory
From biometric.bmstu.ru:test
 ! [new branch]      try_merge  -> biometric/try_merge  (unable to update local ref)
Done


$git fsck output

error: bad ref for refs/remotes/biometric/try_merge
```

When i try to push something to remote git  thinks that it is a brand new branch for remote repository.
How can I recover it?

Sorry for bad english.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've fixed this with manual editing of  refs/remotes/try_merge (it was full of nul values). I've copied sha1 value from  last merged commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've reversed the matching ref syntax, looks like. It should be `<remote_ref>:<local_ref>`, but otherwise it looks like you're just attempting to pull `biometric/try_merge` and force it into your local's `try_merge`. Try this:

```
git checkout try_merge
git pull --force biometric try_merge
```

Otherwise I think this will work if you'd like to keep the matching ref syntax:

```
git pull biometric +try_merge:try_merge
```

Let me know in comments if these still throw your error, but either should work.

Comment: Actually , I do not execute git commands manually. This comand is generated and executed by Git Extensions, as i've said i had a bad ref for remote branch and i fixed it with right sha value. But anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Glad you got it worked out. Didn't catch the git extensions reference at first.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and fixed it by simply removing the troublesome branch in .git/refs/remotes/origin/ and then do git fetch again.

Comment: Solved my issue. The ref file contained invalid characters. Deleting removed the error.